# Can I cancel my axa travel insurance and how

Tags: schengen, insurance

I bought an axa travel insurance 8 days ago for my Greece trip. But now I got COVID and I'm trying to cancel it using their form:
https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/contact-us

However, they never allowed me to proceed and always denied my entry for last name:

[image]

I'm sure I didn't enter any novel characters.

So is it really because I am not allowed to cancel???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I just found an answer to my own question.
It seems that they don't think my two-letter last name is a valid one!!!

I added three spaces before my last name and it worked for the system!

Such weird bug!

～～～～update on 20 Dec 2021～～～～

They just confirmed that my insurance contract will be cancelled:

> Dear Sir/Madam
>
> As requested, we have cancelled the policy number XXXXX
>
> The policy has been cancelled and the amount of the prime will be
> refund in the 30 days to your credit card that was used to make the
> booking,
>
> Regards,
>
> AXA SCHENGEN

Comment: See: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @xngtng Amusingly, I don't see "names must be at least n characters long" in that (seemingly exhaustive) list. And "Try to make less" should, of course, be "Try to make **fewer**".